# How to express this logic circuit with output feedback as boolean expression?

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

Q1. How to express this circuit as boolean expression? It uses the output as input (feedback??) to part of the circuit. Is it a special type of circuit?

Q2. How do I simplify it as Nand-only expression for easy implementation? I have a 74HC00 chip (Quad 2-Input NAND Gate). Will this fit within 4 Nand-gates? I am also ok with NOT of output - then i will use a active-low relay.

Context: Input A = PIR sensor (which stays high for X seconds), Input B = Light sensor (low = low light). When A is HIGH (PIR sensor detects activity) and B is LOW (ambient light is low), turn output HIGH (relay to overhead light). But now since the overhead light is on, B will go HIGH - without feedback, this will instantly turn off the overhead light defeating the purpose. So, I want to pass output back as input - if output is already high, Input B should not matter, only Input A going low will change the output.

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: It's a flip flop. Maybe try looking how flip-flops express it.

Answer (score 1):

A2. Turning it into a NAND circuit mechanically:

Replace AND with NAND. Now output is inverted.

Change OR to NAND. Now the other input needs to be inverted, too: drop inverter/NOT.
Output of this "bottom" NAND is *not* always the complement of the top one:
Either use it as *an active-low* signal,
or invest another NAND to invert that signal to the original.

Two to three NANDs all told, looking much more a ¬R¬S flip-flop (A1b?).